# How to remove .test.js files from webpack build

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I need to remove all the `.test.js` files from my React project.
I am getting errors after building the app.

> **Module parse failed: Unexpected token** 
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
>
>  If I remove the `rules` and change it to just `exclude: /node_modules/` the error goes away but the `BundleAnalyzerPlugin` still displays the .`test.js` files so I assume the webpack didn't removed them.

##### Current Webpack Config

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: false,
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    app: [path.join(config.srcDir, 'index.js')],
  },
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'named',
    chunkIds: 'named',
    minimize: true,
    nodeEnv: 'production',
    mangleWasmImports: true,
    removeEmptyChunks: false,
    mergeDuplicateChunks: false,
    flagIncludedChunks: true,
    minimizer: [`...`, 
    new CssMinimizerPlugin({
      minimizerOptions: {
        preset: [
          "default",
          {
            calc: false,
            discardComments: { removeAll: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
    '...'],
    emitOnErrors: true,
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      minSize: 20000,
      minRemainingSize: 0,
      minChunks: 1,
      maxAsyncRequests: 30,
      maxInitialRequests: 30,
      enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
      cacheGroups: {
        defaultVendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
    path: config.distDir,
    publicPath: BASE_PATH,
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: { "querystring": false },
    modules: ['node_modules', config.srcDir],
    alias: {
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/components'),
      Context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/context'),
      Images: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/images'),
      Plugins: path.resolve(__dirname, '../plugins'),
      Redux: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/redux'),
      Routes: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/routes'),
      Styles: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/styles'),
      Utils: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/utils'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new CircularDependencyPlugin({
      exclude: /a\.js|node_modules/,
      failOnError: true,
      allowAsyncCycles: false,
      cwd: process.cwd(),
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: config.srcHtmlLayout,
      inject: 'body',
      title: 'AdminUI',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
        BASE_PATH: JSON.stringify(BASE_PATH),
        API_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify(API_BASE_URL),
        CONFIG_API_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify(CONFIG_API_BASE_URL),
        SESSION_TIMEOUT_IN_MINUTES: JSON.stringify(SESSION_TIMEOUT_IN_MINUTES),
      },
    }),
    new PurgeCSSPlugin({ paths: glob.sync(`${PATHS.src}/**/*`,  { nodir: true }) }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
      resourceRegExp: /\.test\.js$/,
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [config.srcDir, config.pluginsDir],
        exclude: /(node_modules|\.test\.js$)/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        sideEffects: false,
      },
      // Modular Styles
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
        exclude: [path.resolve(config.srcDir, 'styles')],
        include: [config.srcDir],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
        include: [path.resolve(config.srcDir, 'styles')],
      },
      // Fonts
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '/fonts/[name].[ext]',
          esModule: false,
        },
      },
      // Files
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '/static/[name].[ext]',
          esModule: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: false,
    //contentBase: config.distDir,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: BASE_PATH,
    },
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 4100,
  },
}
```

FYI, I am using `webpack 5.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `ignore-loader` in the rules I was able to solve the error and remove `.test.js` files from the build.

```
      {
        test: /\.test\.js$/,
        include: [config.srcDir, config.pluginsDir],
        use: 'ignore-loader',
      }
```

Comment: explanation, please

Comment: @johnk ignore-loader causes webpack to ignore files matching the `test` parameter.

Comment: Please add that you may need to install ignore-loader with: `npm install --save-dev ignore-loader`

Answer (score 0):

`exclude` property to specify that any files matching the pattern `/test\.js$/` should be excluded from the webpack build. This should prevent test.js files from being included in the output bundle.

Note that the exclude property uses a regular expression pattern to match file names, so you'll need to escape any special characters (like the dot) using a backslash.

```
module.exports = {
  // ... other config options
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /test\.js$/, // exclude any files with the name test.js
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: yes but i am still getting the error i mentioned above. any idea what's that about?

Comment: please recheck webpack you might forgot remove few lines after replacing

Comment: I double checked but the results are the same.

Comment: this specific error is only for .test.js files, could the reason be that I have not provided any loader to handle this file?

Comment: @hitesh I added another rule that solved the error. `{
        test: /\.test\.js$/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },`
how can i exclude them now?